# HttpClient WARNING: Cookie rejected: Illegal domain attribute

Tags: java, cookies, warnings, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient latest version (4.x). And right now I'm trying to do A GET Request.
I just posting a Get request.

This is my Code;

```
public class Poster {

    static boolean routing1 = true, routing2 = true;
    static int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;
    DefaultHttpClient oHtp = null;
    HttpGet oHGet = null;
    HttpResponse oHRes = null;


    private void test(String fullAddress) throws Exception {
        oHtp = new DefaultHttpClient();
        oHGet = new HttpGet(fullAddress);

        HttpResponse response = oHtp.execute(oHGet);
        System.out.print(response.getStatusLine());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            //  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            System.out.print("\t entity is retrieved... ");
        }


        oHtp.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

I just execute it nicely.
First is

```
new Poster().test("http://123.xl.co.id/profile.php");
```

and second is

```
 new Poster().test("http://goklik.co.id/");
```

ya, And Only the Second one.... I got this The error message;

> Sep 18, 2011 10:11:30 AM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: CookiePst][value:
>   0149=xwGHF7HYDHLHQ84Isp/eSy9vu+Xq6cT12wxg1A==][domain:
>   .mcore.com][path: /][expiry: Sun Sep 18 10:38:59 ICT 2011]". Illegal
>   domain attribute "mcore.com". Domain of origin: "goklik.co.id"

I realized that the Cookie is involved here. But I don't understand what the Warning means. And I also don't know how to solve it (Cookie not being rejected). Hope there is a bit of light to clear my mind from you guys.... :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't "fix" it. The site is trying to set a cookie it's not allowed to set and the apache client library you're using is telling you about it.

It's trying to set a cookie for `mcore.com` when the domain is `goklik.co.id`

Comment: hah?? are you sure about that?? 
OMG. i thought, from a client side (my side), I should re-create my cookie before giving another GET request (passing along the cookie) that use mcore.com instead of the required goklik.co.id :(

Comment: You're using a client the conforms to proper standards. Looking at the JavaDocs for `org.apache.http.client` I don't see a way to override that (the available org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy options are all standards compliant).

Comment: I am having the same problem but I sent request to the same site. What do you mean "The site is trying to set a cookie it's not allowed to set ". Why this is problem? In my case(the same site), do I really have no way o fix this?

Answer (score 26):

Maybe it's too late, but I had the same problem and I've found something that helped me work it out, just set the [Cookie Policy](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/cookie/CookiePolicy.html) to Browser Compability:

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
        CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

Here are the possible values:

> The cookie policy provides corresponding cookie management interfrace
>   for a given type or version of cookie.
>
> RFC 2109 specification is used per default. Other supported
>   specification can be chosen when appropriate or set default when
>   desired
>
> The following specifications are provided:
>
> - `BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY`: compatible with the common cookie management practices (even if they are not 100% standards compliant)
> - `NETSCAPE`: Netscape cookie draft compliant
> - `RFC_2109`: RFC2109 compliant (default)
> - `IGNORE_COOKIES`: do not automcatically process cookies

Comment: I had the same issue but since I wasn't interested in cookies, I set  CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES and that did it for me (with BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY I kept getting the message).

Comment: What does this message mean and what is CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY mean?

Answer (score 17):

Before `httpclient` 4.3, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324927) in the same page is cool.

But **since** `httpclient` 4.3, API seems changed a lot, following code would work:

```
RequestConfig customizedRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY).build();
HttpClientBuilder customizedClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(customizedRequestConfig);
CloseableHttpClient client = customizedClientBuilder.build(); // customized client,
```

Comment: _Jonathan Silva's answer_ – the user might have changed their name (I suppose to Jon Cardoso), so a link might be better than calling them by name

Comment: @törzsmókus Thanks, I have updated the answer as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I am using http client 4.5.2 and this is set cookie spec to easy solved my problem. The example of how instantiate client:

```
httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                        // Waiting for a connection from connection manager
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
                        // Waiting for connection to establish
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setExpectContinueEnabled(false)
                        // Waiting for data
                        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .setCookieSpec("easy")
                        .build())
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(20)
                .setMaxConnTotal(100)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest way to suppress the warning in **v4.5.x** (**4.5.6 right now**) :

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.disableCookieManagement();
HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to improve Eric's answer, as it doesnt directly solve my scenario but changing CookieSpecs to IGNORE_COOKIES solves my problem.

```
RequestConfig customizedRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES).build();
HttpClientBuilder customizedClientBuilder = 
HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(customizedRequestConfig);
CloseableHttpClient client = customizedClientBuilder.build(); // customized client,
```

Because in my version of HttpClient 4.5 CookieSpecs.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY is already depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to process cookies you can simply disable it, with `org.apache.http.impl.cookie.IgnoreSpecProvider` or `org.apache.http.impl.cookie.IgnoreSpec` depending on what API you use. Calling `disableCookieManagement()` on `HttpClientBuilder` is not enough